What is a best way to do backups of Linux-based application running on computer with two disks?
I have a nettop PC on which the Proxmox VME is installed. There is a VM running there, which hosts application (on Ubuntu OS).
This PC has two SSDs installed. On first disk the Proxmox is installed with that VM, the second one is empty, not used.
What I want to achive:
The application running on Ubuntu makes a backup each week (one per week) and saves it on that first disk. The outcome of such backup is just a directory with files. It is enough to restore all application data on another nettop PC with same Proxmox and same Ubuntu OS. It's done using that application itself.
I want to secure myself from loosing data when the first disks will die.
I was thinking mainly about two solutions:

To copy only that backup folder to second disk.
To do whole VM backup and store it on the second disk.

What solution will be better?
Let's assume that the first disk dies. I take another nettop PC with the Proxmox installed and VM Ubuntu running and put that backup disk to it's free slot. Will I be able to somehow get the backup data from that disk?

Welcome. In principle backup everything, VMs and data. You should IMO start with questions: What data loss is critical? What is that data used for? How often should do I backup and why? How can I restore the data? What is the space available? Etc. Example: if you have a database, the critical loss is the data in that database, not the VM that holds the server. You should (first) secure the backup of the database, not the VM (which also will need much more space). Now with your database backup you can restore it to a new/different VM. The scenarios are endless.
